# Serialize and Deserialize in unity3d

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine

During to developing small app in **unity3D** I faced one problem. I use Sockets to send data from server to client. Both client and server have one same class, so data in server in serialized, send and then deserialized in client.(Sending data is about 1 MB, it consists file). When I use c# console application project, instead unity3d it works ok, getting data from server performs without delay. But in unity3d it does not. Problem is while deserializing object.(once in 10 try is work ok )). Can anybody explain whats matter? (I can show my code if it'll help)

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be nice, an *error message* would be even nicer.

Is your C# console application project built using mono bundled with unity? If not, know that unity's .NET implementation is far from either Microsoft's .NET and modern Mono.

Apart from that, serialization is a very irritating topic in Unity, as it happens to trigger quite a few problems:

- First, serialization is trimmed, some stuff is just not there in the runtime. This is a design choice by the Unity Team.
- Second, to have good custom serialization you need reflection, which is also not completely available. Especially in iOS and webplayer, where you don't have the standard [Just In Time compilation (JIT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) but it's IMO poorer equivalent of [Ahead Of Time compilation (AOT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler).
- Third, every platform unity compiles to differs in implementation of generics in JIT/AOT and details how reflection works runtime, so be prepared to test everything everywhere extra careful.

Look into [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json), it is quite useful in Unity. Far from perfect, but most stuff works after some hacking. Some of this hacking is already made in a $20 asset store package if you want (far from perfect, but in simple use cases it is enough - have to push my patches one day)

Comment: At first thanks for reply. So, error message while deserializing is "SerializationException: Unexpected binary element: 0".

Comment: At first thanks for reply. So, error message while desalinizing is "SerializationException: Unexpected binary element: 0". My C# application is standalone and has no link to unity, it directly connects to socket server. As for JSON.NET, I think it will not be useful in my case, because socket server sends only byte(or string)

Answer (score 0):

I read your comment "As for JSON.NET, I think it will not be useful in my case, because socket server sends only byte (or string)".

You can just serialize JSON to string. And then get your bites like this:

```
byte[] jsonData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (yourJsonGoesHere)
```

and your string JSON bytes ready to send from or to server. Second, if you are using binaryformatter try read binaryformatter.binder in documentation.